# How to catch errors when refresh nested materialized views

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

Materialized View "MV_AMP":

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_AMP
  NOLOGGING
  BUILD IMMEDIATE
  REFRESH FORCE
  ON DEMAND
AS
Select a, b, c from amp;
```

Materialized View "MV_BOT" that dependens on "MV_AMP":

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_BOT
  NOLOGGING
  BUILD IMMEDIATE
  REFRESH FORCE
  ON DEMAND
AS
SELECT bot.x, bot.y, mv_amp 
FROM bot, mv_amp
WHERE bot.a = mv_amp.a;
```

And create a unique index in mv_bot:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX mv_bot_idx001 ON mv_bot(x, a);
```

After views and index create successful, suppose I add a duplicate value that cause an error like (dup_val_on_index) when refresh the mv_bot due the unique index.

So I do a refresh in MV_AMP (the main view) using nested=TRUE, and Oracle didn't raise an error:

```
BEGIN
  dbms_mview.refresh_dependent(number_of_failures => n_failures,
                                   list => 'MV_AMP',
                                   atomic_refresh => TRUE,
                                   nested => TRUE);

EXCEPTION
  WHEN
    OTHERS THEN
        -- it never reach this code
        dbms_output.put_line('Errors: '||SQLERRM);
END;
```

n_failures returns: 0 and it never reaches the dbms_output inside the exception.

I need to catch the error when oracle tries to updates the nested MVs and log in a table.

Using Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EXCEPTION` block ist reached only in case there is a duplicated row in the materialized view `MV_BOT` - which is not the case.

You may ask why; the most probalble answer is that you **need to refresh the materialized view `MV_AMP` as well** to get the dup in the join of `MV_BOT`.

While reading the documentation of [`dbms_mview.refresh_dependent`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_mview.htm#ARPLS67207) you realize, that you must start with the table `AMP` to get both MV's refreshed (starting with `MV_AMP` refreshes only the *dependent MV* `MV_BOT`)

**Test Case**

```
create table amp (
a number,
b number,
c number);

create table bot (
a number,
x number,
y number);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_AMP
  NOLOGGING
  BUILD IMMEDIATE
  REFRESH FORCE
  ON DEMAND
AS
Select a, b, c from amp;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_BOT
  NOLOGGING
  BUILD IMMEDIATE
  REFRESH FORCE
  ON DEMAND
AS
SELECT bot.x, bot.y, mv_amp.a 
FROM bot, mv_amp
WHERE bot.a = mv_amp.a;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX mv_bot_idx001 ON mv_bot(x, a);

insert into amp(a,b,c) values(1,1,1);
insert into bot(a,x,y) values(1,1,1);
insert into bot(a,x,y) values(1,1,3);
commit;

DECLARE
  n_failures NUMBER;
BEGIN
  dbms_mview.refresh_dependent(number_of_failures => n_failures,
                                   list => 'AMP',
                                   atomic_refresh => TRUE,
                                   nested => TRUE);
   dbms_output.put_line('Failures: '||n_failures);                                                                
EXCEPTION
  WHEN
    OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Errors: '||SQLERRM);
END;
/

--> Errors: ORA-12008: error in materialized view refresh path
--> ORA-00001: unique constraint (xxxxx.MV_BOT_IDX001) violated
```

Comment: Maybe my example is not explain exactly the issue. Please, ignore  the values presented in the example tables, consider just these 2 MVs, MV_BOT depends on MV_AMP. In the real scenario, duplicated row occurs in the MV_BOT because it have joins with the other tables that cause this. If I not start the refresh with "MV_AMP" how I known the master table of this view? In the real scenario it has a select with 3 ou 4 different tables.

Comment: @Joel my point in other words - you refresh PL/SQL does only refresh of `MV_BOT` and keeps the `MV_APP` unchanged. You must select some source of `MV_APP`(here `APP`) as the starting point to refresh both MVs.

Comment: Tried started the dbms_mview.refresh_dependent with a master table from the MV_AMP, but unfortunately got the same result. MV_BOT wasn't updated due the duplicate values on index, and the refresh process didn't raised any error.

Comment: @Joel I added a reproducible example triggering the `unique constraint`exception. You may try to generalize to your mileage. Note also that in your `MV_BOT` DDL is a **syntax error** which I fixed using `mv_amp.a` instead of `mv_amp` - hope this is typo only.